# Add more metadata to data dump

Tags: discussion, feature-request, data-dump, metadata

I think that there should be more metadata in [data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/). There are currently 4 sites in the dump, and more will come (SE 2.0 sites, stackapps.com).

I am proposing that a new file is added to data dump for each site. This would help to create tools that access several data dumps.

I am thinking this kind of data:

metadata.xml:

```
<metadata>
  <dataDumpVersion>1.0</dataDumpVersion>
  <name>Stack Overflow</name>
  <url>http://stackoverflow.com/</url>
  <description>Stack Overflow is a programming Q & A site that's free. Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it.</description>
  <license>http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/</license>

  <dataDumpCreated>2010-06-07 12:23:42</dataDumpCreated>
  <dataDumpStart>2008-09-15 12:23:42</dataDumpStart>
  <dataDumpEnd>2010-05-31 23:59:59</dataDumpEnd>

  <includedFiles>
    <file>posts.xml</file>
    <file>users.xml</file>
    <file>badges.xml</file>
    <file>comments.xml</file>
  <includedFiles>
</metada>
```